# How to optimize Django view for performance?

Tags: django, django-orm

I am wondering what the best practices are for optimizing view performance.

I have this view that takes over 90 seconds to load (with 5 queries, 2 of which take the bulk of time). It has some complex queries, which a few Subqueries and a bunch of calculations. Should I try to split all these calculations in different views, use async for the calculations or use caching (I am fairly new to programming and Django)?

Edit:  This view is supposed to calculate the (salary) base amount and the bonus for each Dispatcher. A dispatcher can have BonusCustomers, for which they receive an extra bonus.

The base amount (per dispatcher) is the average weekly miles from the last 2 weeks * the set rate per location.

The bonus (per dispatcher) is the set bonus per customer (field of Dispatcher) * sum of relevant jobs (loads) from dispatcher's BonusCustomers. If the company weekly rate per mile for the last 2 weeks (billable amount / total_miles) is higher than the customer rate per mile for the last week, then relevant jobs are all loads from past week for all BonusCustomers for this specific Dispatcher.

```
    def dispatchers_list(request):
        tenant = get_tenant(request)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.GET.get('date_range') is not None:
            date_range = request.GET.get('date_range')
            date_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_range.split('-')[0].strip(), '%m/%d/%Y')
            date_end = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_range.split('-')[1].strip(), '%m/%d/%Y')
            custom_week_nr = get_week_number(date_end.date())
            year = int(date_end.strftime("%Y"))
            date_start_string = date_start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
            date_end_string = date_end.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

        else:
            date_start = start_week_nr(CURRENT_YEAR, CURRENT_WEEK_CUSTOM-1)
            date_start = datetime.datetime.combine(date_start, datetime.datetime.min.time())
            date_end = date_start + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
            custom_week_nr = get_week_number(date_end.date())
            year = int(date_end.strftime("%Y"))
            date_start_string = date_start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
            date_end_string = date_end.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
            date_range = f"{date_start_string} - {date_end_string}"
    
        date_start_miles = datetime.datetime.combine(date_start - datetime.timedelta(days=7), datetime.datetime.min.time())
    
        date_end_miles = date_start_miles + datetime.timedelta(days=14)
   
    
        # Calculate company rate per mile for last 2 weeks
        company_loads_last_2_weeks = Load.objects.filter(drop_date__gte=date_start_miles, drop_date__lt=date_end_miles).exclude(load_status='Cancelled').aggregate(billable_amount=Sum('billable_amount'), total_miles=Sum('total_miles'))
        if company_loads_last_2_weeks['billable_amount'] is not None and company_loads_last_2_weeks['total_miles'] is not None:
            company_rate_per_mile = company_loads_last_2_weeks['billable_amount'] / company_loads_last_2_weeks['total_miles']
        else:
            company_rate_per_mile = 0
     


        loads_subquery = Load.objects.filter(
            customer=OuterRef('customer'),  # Reference the customer field of the current BonusCustomer
            drop_date__gte=date_start_miles,
            drop_date__lt=date_end_miles 
        ).exclude(load_status='Cancelled'
        ).values('customer'
        ).annotate(
            total_revenue=Sum('billable_amount', default=0),
            total_miles=Sum('total_miles', default=0)
        )

        loads_subquery_all_jobs = Load.objects.filter(
            customer=OuterRef('customer'),
            drop_date__gte=date_start,
            drop_date__lt=date_end 
        ).exclude(load_status='Cancelled'
        ).values('customer'
        ).annotate(
            all_jobs=Count('id')
        )


        loads_subquery_all_jobs_pick_city = Load.objects.filter(
            customer=OuterRef('customer'),
            pick_city=OuterRef('pick_city'),
            drop_date__gte=date_start,
            drop_date__lt=date_end 
        ).exclude(load_status='Cancelled'
        ).values('customer'
        ).annotate(
            all_jobs=Count('id')
        )


        loads_subquery_jobs_excl_dispatcher = Load.objects.filter(
            customer=OuterRef('customer'),
            drop_date__gte=date_start,
            drop_date__lt=date_end
        ).exclude(load_status='Cancelled'
        ).exclude(sales_agent=OuterRef('dispatcher__name')
        ).values('customer'
        ).annotate(
            jobs_excl_dispatcher=Count('id')
        )


        loads_subquery_jobs_excl_dispatcher_pick_city = Load.objects.filter(
            customer=OuterRef('customer'),
            pick_city=OuterRef('pick_city'),
            drop_date__gte=date_start,
            drop_date__lt=date_end
        ).exclude(load_status='Cancelled'
        ).exclude(sales_agent=OuterRef('dispatcher__name')
        ).values('customer'
        ).annotate(
            jobs_excl_dispatcher=Count('id')
        )

    # Annotate the BonusCustomer queryset with the calculated sum
    bonus_customers = BonusCustomer.objects.select_related('dispatcher').annotate(
        customer_revenue=Subquery(loads_subquery.values('total_revenue'), output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)),
        customer_miles=Subquery(loads_subquery.values('total_miles'), output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)),
        customer_rpm = F('customer_revenue') / F('customer_miles'),
        pick_city_null = ExpressionWrapper(Q(pick_city=''), output_field=BooleanField()),
        all_jobs = Coalesce(
            Case(
                When(pick_city_null=True, then=Subquery(loads_subquery_all_jobs.values('all_jobs'), output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2))),
                When(pick_city_null=False, then=Subquery(loads_subquery_all_jobs_pick_city.values('all_jobs'), output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)))
            ), 0, output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
        ),
        jobs_excl_dispatcher = Coalesce(
            Case(
                When(pick_city_null=True, then=Subquery(loads_subquery_jobs_excl_dispatcher.values('jobs_excl_dispatcher'), output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2))),
                When(pick_city_null=False, then=Subquery(loads_subquery_jobs_excl_dispatcher_pick_city.values('jobs_excl_dispatcher'), output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)))
            ), 0, output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
        ),
        jobs_for_bonus = Coalesce(
            Case(
                When(customer_rpm__gte=Decimal(company_rate_per_mile), then='jobs_excl_dispatcher'),
                When(customer_rpm__lt=Decimal(company_rate_per_mile), then='all_jobs')
            ), 0, output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
        ),
    ).order_by('customer')
    

    dispatchers = Dispatcher.objects.select_related('company', 'location').annotate(
        num_of_loads=Count('load', filter=Q(load__drop_date__gte=date_start, load__drop_date__lt=date_end_miles)&~Q(load__load_status='Cancelled')),
        loads_miles = Sum(F('load__total_miles')/2, filter=Q(load__drop_date__gte=date_start_miles, load__drop_date__lt=date_end_miles)&~Q(load__load_status='Cancelled'), default=0),
        base_rate = Subquery(BaseRate.objects.filter(location=OuterRef('location')).values('rate')),
        base_amount_model_null = ExpressionWrapper(Q(base_amount__isnull=True), output_field=BooleanField()),
        base_amt = Case(
            When(base_amount_model_null=False, then='base_amount'),
            When(base_amount_model_null=True, then=F('loads_miles')*F('base_rate'))
        ),
        bonus_jobs=Coalesce(
            Subquery(bonus_customers.filter(dispatcher=OuterRef('pk')).order_by().values('dispatcher').annotate(jobs_sum=Sum('jobs_for_bonus')).values('jobs_sum')), 0, output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0)
        ),
        bonus_amount_new=Coalesce(
            F('bonus_jobs')*F('bonus_per_customer'), 0, output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0))
        )


    context = {
        'tenant': tenant,
        'dispatchers': dispatchers,
        'bonus_customers': bonus_customers,
        'date_range': date_range,
        'date_start': date_start_string,
        'date_end': date_end_string
    }
    return render(request, template_name='dispatchers/dispatcher-list.html', context=context)
```

The SQL query that takes about 80 seconds looks like this:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "dispatchers_baserate" U0 WHERE U0."location_id" = ("dispatchers_dispatcher"."location_id") ORDER BY U0."id" ASC) AS "base_rate", "dispatchers_dispatcher"."base_amount" IS NULL AS "base_amount_model_null", CASE WHEN NOT ("dispatchers_dispatcher"."base_amount" IS NULL) THEN "dispatchers_dispatcher"."base_amount" WHEN ("dispatchers_dispatcher"."base_amount" IS NULL) THEN (COALESCE(SUM(("loads_load"."total_miles" / 2)) FILTER (WHERE ("loads_load"."drop_date" >= '2023-08-19T00:00:00'::timestamp AND "loads_load"."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT ("loads_load"."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND "loads_load"."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL))), 0) * (SELECT U0."rate" FROM "dispatchers_baserate" U0 WHERE U0."location_id" = ("dispatchers_dispatcher"."location_id") ORDER BY U0."id" ASC)) ELSE NULL END AS "base_amt", COALESCE((SELECT SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN (((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(U0."billable_amount"), 0) AS "total_revenue" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-19T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") / (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(U0."total_miles"), 0) AS "total_miles" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-19T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer")) >= 2.351170792302661723350413037) THEN COALESCE(CASE WHEN ((V0."pick_city" = '')) THEN (SELECT COUNT(U0."id") AS "jobs_excl_dispatcher" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-26T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL) AND NOT (U0."sales_agent_id" = (V1."name") AND U0."sales_agent_id"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") WHEN (NOT (V0."pick_city" = '')) THEN (SELECT COUNT(U0."id") AS "jobs_excl_dispatcher" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-26T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."pick_city" = (V0."pick_city") AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL) AND NOT (U0."sales_agent_id" = (V1."name") AND U0."sales_agent_id"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") ELSE NULL END, 0) WHEN (((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(U0."billable_amount"), 0) AS "total_revenue" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-19T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") / (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(U0."total_miles"), 0) AS "total_miles" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-19T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer")) < 2.351170792302661723350413037) THEN COALESCE(CASE WHEN ((V0."pick_city" = '')) THEN (SELECT COUNT(U0."id") AS "all_jobs" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-26T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") WHEN (NOT (V0."pick_city" = '')) THEN (SELECT COUNT(U0."id") AS "all_jobs" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-26T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."pick_city" = (V0."pick_city") AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") ELSE NULL END, 0) ELSE NULL END, 0)) AS "jobs_sum" FROM "dispatchers_bonuscustomer" V0 INNER JOIN "dispatchers_dispatcher" V1 ON (V0."dispatcher_id" = V1."id") WHERE V0."dispatcher_id" = ("dispatchers_dispatcher"."id") GROUP BY V0."dispatcher_id"), 0) AS "bonus_jobs", COALESCE((COALESCE((SELECT SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN (((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(U0."billable_amount"), 0) AS "total_revenue" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-19T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") / (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(U0."total_miles"), 0) AS "total_miles" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-19T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer")) >= 2.351170792302661723350413037) THEN COALESCE(CASE WHEN ((V0."pick_city" = '')) THEN (SELECT COUNT(U0."id") AS "jobs_excl_dispatcher" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-26T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL) AND NOT (U0."sales_agent_id" = (V1."name") AND U0."sales_agent_id"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") WHEN (NOT (V0."pick_city" = '')) THEN (SELECT COUNT(U0."id") AS "jobs_excl_dispatcher" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-26T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."pick_city" = (V0."pick_city") AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL) AND NOT (U0."sales_agent_id" = (V1."name") AND U0."sales_agent_id"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") ELSE NULL END, 0) WHEN (((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(U0."billable_amount"), 0) AS "total_revenue" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-19T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") / (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(U0."total_miles"), 0) AS "total_miles" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-19T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer")) < 2.351170792302661723350413037) THEN COALESCE(CASE WHEN ((V0."pick_city" = '')) THEN (SELECT COUNT(U0."id") AS "all_jobs" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-26T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") WHEN (NOT (V0."pick_city" = '')) THEN (SELECT COUNT(U0."id") AS "all_jobs" FROM "loads_load" U0 WHERE (U0."customer" = (V0."customer") AND U0."drop_date" >= '2023-08-26T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."drop_date" < '2023-09-02T00:00:00'::timestamp AND U0."pick_city" = (V0."pick_city") AND NOT (U0."load_status" = 'Cancelled' AND U0."load_status"::text IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY U0."customer") ELSE NULL END, 0) ELSE NULL END, 0)) AS "jobs_sum" FROM "dispatchers_bonuscustomer" V0 INNER JOIN "dispatchers_dispatcher" V1 ON (V0."dispatcher_id" = V1."id") WHERE V0."dispatcher_id" = ("dispatchers_dispatcher"."id") GROUP BY V0."dispatcher_id"), 0) * "dispatchers_dispatcher"."bonus_per_customer"), 0) AS "bonus_amount_new", "dispatchers_location"."id", "dispatchers_location"."location", "dispatchers_company"."id", "dispatchers_company"."name", "dispatchers_company"."address", "dispatchers_company"."phone_nr" FROM "dispatchers_dispatcher" LEFT OUTER JOIN "loads_load" ON ("dispatchers_dispatcher"."name" = "loads_load"."sales_agent_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "dispatchers_location" ON ("dispatchers_dispatcher"."location_id" = "dispatchers_location"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "dispatchers_company" ON ("dispatchers_dispatcher"."company_id" = "dispatchers_company"."id") GROUP BY "dispatchers_dispatcher"."id", 14, 16, 17, "dispatchers_location"."id", "dispatchers_company"."id"
```

The models:

```
class Dispatcher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, editable=True, unique=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    base_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    bonus_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    bonus_per_customer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=25.00)


 class BonusCustomer(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    dispatcher = models.ForeignKey(Dispatcher, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    pick_city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)


class Load(models.Model):
    sales_agent = models.ForeignKey(Dispatcher, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, to_field='name', blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=320, null=True, blank=True)
    pick_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    drop_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    pick_city = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    load_status = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    billable_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    empty_miles = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    total_miles = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)


class BaseRate(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, verbose_name='Base rate')

class Location(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
```

Comment: You start by profiling which query or queries take the longest (e.g. with django-debug-toolbar), and then figuring out from e.g. the `EXPLAIN`  output for your database engine whether there are query optimizations you could make, or indexes to add.  Async won't help, nor splitting them into separate views (since you need all of the data anyway for your template, I assume).

Comment: Perhaps it would help that you first explain *what* the view is supposed to do. I have the impression it contains *way* too much code.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem: I added a bit of clarification to what the view is supposed to calculate.

Comment: AKX: For some reason there is no Explain action next to this query in DDToolbar.

Comment: @Valeriu You can nevertheless copy-paste the query to your favorite SQL tool and slap `EXPLAIN` in front of it.